# how to give background image to captcha and also change font family of captcha?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, captcha

Please friends help me i try atmost to change the background image of captcha but it do not changing  and  also try to change font-family and border radius. please help me if any one to know about that...

```
session_start(); 
$change_time = md5(microtime()); 
$get_value = substr($change_time,0,6); 
$_SESSION['value'] = $get_value; 
$create_image = imagecreate(100,30); 
imagecolorallocate($create_image,51,112,183); 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($create_image,255,255,255); 
imagestring($create_image,50,15,7,$get_value,$text_color); 
header('Content:image/jpeg'); imagejpeg($create_image);
```

Comment: Please add code..

Comment: session_start();
    $change_time = md5(microtime());
    $get_value = substr($change_time,0,6);
$_SESSION['value'] = $get_value;
    $create_image  = imagecreate(100,30);
imagecolorallocate($create_image,51,112,183);
$text_color  = imagecolorallocate($create_image,255,255,255);
imagestring($create_image,50,15,7,$get_value,$text_color);
header('Content:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($create_image);

Comment: I suggest you add Google reCaptcha instead of any other captcha.

Comment: @ErSouravSingh add code in your question not in comment

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy with simple php captcha.
In the config, edit the backgrounds array:

```
'backgrounds' => array(
    'path/and/fileBackground.png',
    ...
)
```